# How to set a custom image in the background of a UITabBarController in Xcode?

Tags: background, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

I am fairly new to coding, and I am trying to place a custom image in the background of my UITabBarController.  I tried doing it through the storyboard, but you can't just drag and drop a UIImageView.  I found code to change the background for the actual Tab Bar, however I want the actual background changed! Thank you in advance!

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: @Desdenova If you're going to add an unannotated link to the documentation, please at least link to the right page.

Comment: @Desdenova that link is for a tab bar.  I am looking to set the BG of the actual controller, not the tab bar.  From other posts on this forum it looks like Apple doesn't let you directly change the background in for a UITabBarController, unless I'm mistaken I will have to figure out the code to work around this. I've seen Apps have custom BG's for the tab bar controller, any help is much appreciated!